# I get an error when I have 2 entries with similar name

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I have two similar posts with the same title I get this error.
I get the error when I access the page with the same name, having other entries with different names work just fine.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at done (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1004:10)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:257:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at games.forEach.game (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\app.js:80:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Game.find (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\app.js:77:15)
    at D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4759:16
    at D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4099:12
    at process.nextTick (D:\DD\documents\100dc\nodejs\gamesplayed\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:35:39)
```

```
app.post('/newentry', (req, res)=> {
    const gameName = req.body.gameName;
    const gameImage = req.body.gameImage;
    const gamedesc = req.body.gamedesc;
    const gameEntry = new Game({title: gameName, description: gamedesc, image: gameImage});
    gameEntry.save();
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/:title', (req, res) => {
    const gameTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.title);
    Game.find((err, games)=> {
        games.forEach(game => {
            const storedGame = _.lowerCase(game.title);
            if (storedGame === gameTitle) {
                res.render('post', {title: game.title, image: game.image, desc: game.description, id: game._id })
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `storedGame === gameTitle` becomes true multiple times through the forEach loop. You can not call `res.render` multiple times during the same request.

Since it looks like you are using mongoose, I would suggest using `Game.find` to actually find what you are looking for, instead of pulling everything from the database and handling the searching yourself.

```
Games.find({title: gameTitle}, (err, games) => {
  // Return what you want to the client.
})
```

This will still cause multiple games to be returned, so you need to handle that in some way before responding to the client.

Also look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), as they make the code look much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when we try to send response more than one time. 
const storedGame = _.lowerCase(game.title) will have multiple values and hence after comparing it will be there in the res.render block more than one time so this error will occur.
So comparing should be done in the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used `find`, it will return all the games.So, You can try something like this.

```
    Game.find((err, games)=> {
        games= games.map(game => {
            const storedGame = _.lowerCase(game.title);
            if (storedGame === gameTitle) {
               return {title: game.title, image: game.image, desc: game.description, id: game._id }
            }
        });
     return res.send(games)
    });
```

Or another way is to use `findOne` method of ORM to find only one record.